# ¿Cómo modificar un svg con css?

Tags: html, css, botón

Estoy tratando de cambiar el tamaño (alto y ancho) de un svg con css pero al hacerlo, la imagen se ve cortada. Lo que necesito es reducir su tamaño a 50px.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le di un width y height de 50px pero esto eso es lo que se ve.

Esta es la estructura html del botón (si agrego 50 en lugarr del 94 que tiene el svg, se ve igualmente cortada):

```css
 button {
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   padding: 0;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

svg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span class="sr-only">Play video</span>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="94" height="94">
          <path fill="#FAF9F7" d="M47 0C21.084 0 0 21.084 0 47s21.084 47 47 47 47-21.084 47-47S72.916 0 47 0zm24.326 48.816L37.41 72.723a1.51 1.51 0 0 1-.868.277c-.247 0-.495-.06-.72-.185A1.6 1.6 0 0 1 35 71.406V23.594a1.6 1.6 0 0 1 .822-1.41 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.59.093l33.916 23.906c.42.297.672.79.672 1.317 0 .527-.253 1.02-.674 1.316z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Hola generalmente basta con asignar un atributo ej: height : 50px y el complementario (en este caso width) a auto `svg { margin: 0 auto; width: 50px; height: auto; }` Eso garantiza que la imagen no se deforme. En cuanto al recorte, debe haber algún otro atributo o asignación que lo provoca. Ha debido deformarse si no era cuadrada.

Comment: Acabo de ver que en el html tienes `width="94" height="94"` eso seguramente incide en el recorte. Prueba a quitarlos y deja solo el css

Answer (score 3):

El error tiene que ver con el atributo `viewBox` más info [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

```html
<button>
    <span class="sr-only">Play video</span>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="94" height="94" viewBox="0 0 94 94">introducir el código aquí
          <path fill="#FAF9F7" d="M47 0C21.084 0 0 21.084 0 47s21.084 47 47 47 47-21.084 47-47S72.916 0 47 0zm24.326 48.816L37.41 72.723a1.51 1.51 0 0 1-.868.277c-.247 0-.495-.06-.72-.185A1.6 1.6 0 0 1 35 71.406V23.594a1.6 1.6 0 0 1 .822-1.41 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.59.093l33.916 23.906c.42.297.672.79.672 1.317 0 .527-.253 1.02-.674 1.316z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo te aconsejaría es que si quieres mantener bien la relación aspecto trabajes con lo siguiente:

```
svg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: scale(.5);
}
```

O bien con porcentajes.